# store a big array into the MySQL table

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am implementing a RESTful webservice for an Android Application. For this app I need to create `stops` table in the mysql database with the folowing colmumns `id, long, lat, route, name, arrivaltime` so the app will every minute query the server to retrieve the route number from the table and depend on the rider position as well as the arrivaltime popup windows will appear to ask the user whether the bus arrives the stop where he is standing at the moment.

how can I integrate the `the arrivaltime` into the table since it is a big array?

For the server side I am using Jersey.

```
{
   "id": 1
   "stops_name": "Amersham ",
   "arrival_time": {
                    "mon-fri": [ "05:38", "06:07","06:37",.....50 entries],
                    "sat": ["05:34","06:01","06:31",...........50 entries],
                    "son": ["06:02","06:34","07:04",...........50 entries]
                   },
    "stops_lat": 83.837994,
    "stops_long": 18.700423
 }
```

Comment: Use a [One-to-many relationship](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1tox/) between `stop` and `arrival_time`

Comment: MySQL is falling way, way behind compared to other databases when it comes to storing data like this unless you're prepared to split that out into conventional tables. It's worth noting that Postgres 9.4 has very [robust support for JSON data that makes it a compelling alternative](https://www.compose.io/articles/is-postgresql-your-next-json-database/).

Comment: @tadman sounds like the "XML Database" story all over again - just because you can doesn't mean you should. If you have a lot of data per field, it should be stored in its own table. Otherwise, logic becomes much more complex and performance suffers. You can't apply indexes *inside* complex data which means you can't query efficiently for eg. the next arrival after Tuesday, 11:32

Comment: @tadman in other words - it's not the databases that fall behind, but misuse of features that causes problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually in Postgres you *can* index inside complex data, Postgres allows indexing based on a function, which is one of the reasons why I recommend it. The [JSON support](https://www.compose.io/articles/is-postgresql-your-next-json-database/) is quite impressive, and gets dramatically better with each version released. Today there's no update-in-place, but that's about to change. Regardless of "misuse of features", the support for SQL in general inside of Postgres is just better. I've used MySQL a lot, but it has its limitations.

Answer (score 1):

Your database layout depends on your requirements.

Option 1:
You create three text columns `arrivaltimemonfri`, `arrivaltimesat`, `arrivaltimeson` that store the arrival times in a format of your choice.

Option 2:
You create two tables. A master table like `stops` with columns `(id, long, lat, route, name)` and a detail table like `arrivaltimes` with columns `(id, stops_id, weekday, arrivaltime)`:

```
1 | 1 | "mon-fri" | 5:38
2 | 1 | "mon-fri" | 6:07
3 | 1 | "mon-fri" | 6:37
...
```

There are of course many other options and each of them has advantages and disadvantages in terms of performance, handling, ...

Comment: for the first option how can I query the seprate value from the text columen  `arrivaltimemonfri, arrivaltimesat, arrivaltimeson`?  for the second option; do you mean in the stops table `(stops_id, long, lat, route, name)`  `stops_id` and not `id` since t is primary key for `stops but forgein key for `arrivaltimes `. And why have not you incremented the id in the `arrivaltimes ` table?

Comment: In the first option you cannot query individual values. Your application has to read the complete list and parse it. In the second option the name of the first column in the `stops` table can be named `id`, even if it matches a foreign key named `stops_id`. But if you prefer `stops_id`, that's fine. And for your last question: My fault, I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that you will have Stop (For stop data), Arrival_Time (for arrival time data) and Day table (For day of week). The relationship between tables are:

1. Stop to Arrival_Time: One to Many
2. Arrival_Time to Day: Many To One

This will ensure that you will have flexibility to update the arrival time for different days. For example, you may have different timetables for each of the days in a week from Monday to Sunday.